# How to display an array

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have to make a Snakes and Ladders game in VB, and I needed some help on making the game board. I wanted to use a 2-D array to make the 100 square game board, and I'm having trouble displaying the game board. This is what I have so far:

```
 Private Sub btnLetsGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLetsGo.Click

    frmGameBoard.Show()
    Me.Hide()

    Call gameBoard()

End Sub


Sub gameBoard()
    Dim SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(9, 9) As String


    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 0) = "1"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 1) = "2"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 2) = "3"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 3) = "4"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 4) = "5"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 5) = "6"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 6) = "7"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 7) = "8"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 8) = "9"
    SnakesAndLaddersGameBoard(0, 9) = "10"



End Sub
```

How can I make this much  show on the form? After that, I'll make the rest of the game board, but I can't even get this much to work.

I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to achieve this-

First--

1. Put a FlowLayoutPanel on form.
2. Add 100 labels to it (dynamically) with numbering 100 to 1

Second--

1. Use graphics to write text on the form (In the 'OnPaint' method, use 'e.DrawString')

Mark as answer if helpful.

Revert if any query.